# Add whitespace to subset of a data frame in r

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to use str_pad on a subset of items in a data frame. So that is, starting with something like:

```
> d <- data.frame(q=c("all","two","a","an","each"),s=c("univ","exis","exis","exis","univ"))
> d
     q    s
1  all univ
2  two exis
3    a exis
4   an exis
5 each univ
```

I'd like to add white space to just the items where the value in q starts with "a" or "e". I can use str_pad and str_subset to get this:

```
> str_pad(str_subset(d$q,"\\b([ae])"),3)
[1] "all"  "  a"  " an"  "each"
```

But I don't know how to change those items in the data frame. I can use subset() to pick out the rows I want to edit, but I'm not sure how to rewrite parts of that subset, it gives me an error:

```
> subset(d,str_detect(d$q,"\\b([ae])")==TRUE)
     q    s
1  all univ
3    a exis
4   an exis
5 each univ
> subset(d,str_detect(d$q,"\\b([ae])")==TRUE)$q <- str_pad(str_subset(d$q,"\\b([ae])"),3)
Error in subset(d, str_detect(d$q, "\\b([ae])") == TRUE)$q <- str_pad(str_subset(d$q,  : 
  could not find function "subset<-"
```

Is there a short-ish way to do this? I can think of a couple roundabout ways but something brief would be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an efficient way to do it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d <- data.frame(q = c("all","two","a","an","each"),
           s = c("univ","exis","exis","exis","univ")) %>%
  mutate(q = ifelse(str_detect(q, '^[ae]'), paste(' ', q), q))
d$q
```

The output:

```
[1] "  all"  "two"    "  a"    "  an"   "  each"
```

Let us know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This does the job for the rows I'm targeting but for some reason changed the q value on the other row to "5". Not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: i don't exactly understand what you mean.. can you elaborate on it?

Comment: In the row from the original data frame that wasn't picked out by str_detect, the value was changed to "5" rather than being left as "two"

Comment: Huh it's actually working on other data. I'm not sure what was going on with my toy example but otherwise it seems to work just fine!

Comment: it's great news @MichaelClauss, I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

d_2 <- d %>%
    dplyr::mutate(result = if_else(stringr::str_detect(q, "^a")|
                                   stringr::str_detect(q, "^e"), paste(" ", q), q))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
d$q <- sub('^([ae])', " \\1", d$q)
d$q
#[1] " all"  "two"   " a"    " an"   " each"
```